# is nvl function based on not null constraint

Tags: sql

Please clarify the usage of `NVL` function.

I need to insert a value, 999999, if a value is not found from the `SELECT` query, but the table's column where the value gets inserted is of type `NOT NULL`, and the table on which we do a select query to get the value is also of type `NOT NULL`.

SOURCE (used to get column values to load into T_DATA table)

```
COLUMN_NAME   DATA_TYPE    NULLABLE    COLUMN_ID
SRC_ID        NUMBER       No          1
```

T_DATA table (to load table)

```
COLUMN_NAME  DATA_TYPE   NULLABLE
SRC_ID       NUMBER      No
```

`INSERT` query:

```
INSERT INTO T_DATA
(select (SELECT NVL(SRC_ID,999999) FROM SOURCE 
     WHERE SRC_DESC = LTRIM(TABLE_ID)), class_code,line_number,sysdate 
   from T_VB_DATA);
```

Because `SRC_ID` IN TABLE source is `NOT NULL`, even if I use the `NVL` function, it is not going to do anything.  So, am I correct in assuming that it should accept a `NULL` value?

The column when it is inserted into the `t_data` table can not be `NULL`.

Comment: Please don't shout at us, thanks...

Comment: If you query table t_vb_data for null values, do you find any?  Also, your posted query has syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the `NVL` function correctly. Based on your description, it sounds like you don't actually need to use the `NVL` function because the `SRC_ID` column in the `SOURCE` will never have a `NULL`.  Also the target table getting loaded `T_DATA` can have the NOT NULL constraint because the example insert query you've given won't attempt to insert `null` values into that column.

Is there an error message when you try to execute insert statement? Or are you you just working on the design details and want to get confirmation that you understand the NVL function and how to make sure that you insert a default value instead of `null`?